# How can I call uianimation on imageView looks like Circle

Tags: xcode, uiimage, uianimation

I want to create circle uiimageview animation. When uiimage finished at `self.left` immediately calls again from after `uiimageview.right`.  I want to call animation looks like but my animation was bad. Because when it finished `self.left`, it started `self.right`. :(  But I want to look like image:

```
[ ----(end of image)---------       --------(start of image)]

Me. I did it.
[ -----(end of image)----------      ]
```

When finished end of image, it coming after.

My code looks like:

```
 //for start 
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    imageView.left = - imageView.width;
    // imageView2.left = - imageView.width;


    [UIView setAnimationDuration:140.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(moveToLeft:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];




-(void)moveToLeft:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context 
{ 
     imageView.left = self.right;
     imageView2.left = self.right + 3600;




     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:140.0];
     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
     imageView.left = -imageView.right;

     imageView2.left = -imageView2.right;





    //  imageView.left = - imageView.width;
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(moveToLeft:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];



   // imageView.frame.origin.x = imageView.left - self.right

 }
```

How can i do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using beginAnimations, it's now recommended to use the block based approach (available on iOS4 and higher).

```
[UIVIew animateWithDuration:140.0 delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^(void) {
                     imageView.frame = CGRectMake( *Add Final position here* );
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

The options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse option will ensure that the animation goes backwards and forwards. The UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat option will keep the animation going.

Inside the block add your animation code to where the view should move.  It'll then move back and forwards to that point.

Comment: Oh, and since you're new here you should know that if that solves your problem you should accept the answer using the tick to the left.